# View in popover is missing some, but not all, subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to make a view reveal inside a popover.  Something I have done numerous times.  However, for some reason this time, the popover is appearing but missing some (but not all) of it subviews.

More specifically, this view contains a label, a text field, a button, and also has a navigation bar at the top.  When revealed, it displays a label, but not the text field,  or button.  Ive tried with and without a XIB and results are the same.

Here is the declaration of the popover..  (triggers on button click)

```
if (popover)
{
    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
    popover = nil;
}

// create the settings view controller and display it in a popover
LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginViewController];

// Initialize the popover, set the parent view as the delegate and allocate the popover's origin on the screen
popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:nav];
popover.delegate = self;
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:button.frame inView:button.superview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

and in the view did load of the loginViewController I have

```
self.navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"POPOVER_TITLE_INFORMATION", nil);

// setup navigation buttons
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"BUTTON_TITLE_CANCEL", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancel)];
UIBarButtonItem *searchButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"BUTTON_TITLE_SEARCH", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(search)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = searchButton;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;

[_loginTextLabel setText:NSLocalizedString(@"DESCRIPTION_TEXT", nil)];
[_loginTextLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
_loginTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 30, 728, 40);
[self.view addSubview:_loginTextLabel];

_loginTextField.frame = CGRectMake(20, 80, 264, 30);
[self.view addSubview:_loginTextField];

[_loginSubmitButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"BUTTON_TITLE_SUBMIT", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_loginSubmitButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitBtnClk:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_loginSubmitButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 130, 208, 44)];
[self.view addSubview:_loginSubmitButton];
```

Nothing overly complex, however the label is the only thing that actually displays to the screen.

Comment: First guess would be that you haven't linked the other objects.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

It would seem that Popovers AutoResize their components, and the widths of the button and the textfield were not large enough.  Essentially, the popover screen is smaller than a normal view covering the full window, so it was shrinking the widths of the textField and button all the way to 0 when i guess the popover was adjusting the view.

So basically, I had to jack up the widths of those subviews to compensate.